# Javascript - Uncaught ReferenceError: azZkVUpgbG is not defined, while the console prints my data successfully

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parsing, token

I have the follwing JS function:

```
function setOptions(fullName, userID, qObjID) {
    document.getElementById("reportUserButt").innerHTML = "<a id='reportUserButt' href='javascript:reportUser(" + userID + ");'> <h5>Report @" + fullName + "<span style='opacity: 0.5'> -- " + userID + "</h5></a>";
}
```

which calls this func:

```
// REPORT A USER ---------------------------------------
function reportUser(userID) {
    $('#optionsModal').modal('hide');

    console.log("userID: " + userID);

    // Show loading modal
    document.getElementById("loadingText").innerHTML = "Reporting User, please wait...";
    $('#loadingModal').modal('show');


    $.ajax({
            url:"report-user.php?userID=" + userID, 
            type: "GET", 

            success:function(data) {
                var results = data.replace(/\s+/, ""); //remove any trailing white spaces from returned string
                console.debug(results);

                $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');

                alert("Thanks for reporting this user! We will check it out within 24h.");

                // Reload page
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.reload();
                }, 100);

            // error
            }, error: function (e) { alert(e);}
        });
}
```

So I'm sure that my **reportUserButt** is correct because it shows me the "**userID**" variable in my php page, but the error I get when i click that href is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: azZkVUpgbG is not defined
```

**azZkVUpgbG** is the userID I need, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Userid `azZkVUpgbG` is a string, when you pass it to a function:

```
href='javascript:reportUser(" + userID + ")';
```

the code becomes:

```
href='javascript:reportUser(azZkVUpgbG)';
```

So, as you can see, you call `reportUser` with argument `azZkVUpgbG` which is **not string**.

So, the solution is to add quotes:

```
href='javascript:reportUser(\"" + userID + "\");'
```

Now, your code becomes

```
href='javascript:reportUser("azZkVUpgbG");'
```

and you pass a **string** to a function.